# Need integer output from equation using complex numbers in python

Tags: python, integer, complex-numbers

I have some equation for a type of step function which I obtained with wolfram alpha:

```
a_n = 1/8 (2 n+(-1)^n-(1+i) (-i)^n-(1-i) i^n+9)
```

Using in wolfram with any positive integer will yield me a positive integer result however when I try the following in python

```
import numpy as np
n = 5
i = complex(0,1)
a = (1/8)*((2*n)+(np.power(-1,n))-(1+i)*(np.power(-i,n))-(1-i)*(np.power(i,n))+9)
```

I'm always stuck with some real + imaginary part. I need to be able to obtain an integer output for a for use in other equations.

Comment: Do you need to discard the imaginary part, or do you need the magnitude of the complex number?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want `int(a.real)` at the end.

Also be aware that by default 1/8 will be evaluated as 0 in Python 2.x

Comment: Not sure why the formatting of my code has gone all funny... But when you say at the end... do you mean literally at the end? just like that?

Comment: If it returns only the real component then its going to give a bad output. Have a peek at what it looks like in wolfram alpha, specifically the real part by itself. Then try using the formula with some value for n in wolfram and notice the integer result. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a_n+%3D+1%2F8+%282+n%2B%28-1%29%5En-%281%2Bi%29+%28-i%29%5En-%281-i%29+i%5En%2B9%29+

Comment: I'm not sure how do you want to get an integer from complex number. Can you formulate what you want in math? For some values of n imaginary part is 0, so you can get a real integer result.

Answer (score 0):

```
(1+i) (-i)^n+(1-i) i^n
```

is two times the real part of (1-i) i^n which is, for instance

```
2*cos(pi/2*n)-2*cos(pi/2*(n+1))
```

or as values

```
n            0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
expression   2  2 -2 -2  2  2 -2 -2  2
```

this is subtracted from the alternating sequence to give

```
n            0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
(-1)^n-expr -1 -3  3  1 -1 -3  3  1 -1
```

periodically with period 4

This can be computed avoiding all powers and saveguarding for negative n as

```
3-2*(((n+2) mod 4 +4) mod 4)
```

adding 2n+9 to complete the expression gives

```
12+2*n-2*(((n+2) mod 4 +4) mod 4)
```

which is indeed divisible by 8, so

```
a = 1+(n+2-(((n+2) % 4 +4) % 4) )/4
```

now if one considers that this just reduces (n+2) to the next lower multiple of 4, this is equivalent to the simplified

```
a = 1 + (n+2)/4
```

using integer division.